# check date for variable value

Tags: java, date, comparison

I have a variable in my Java class that needs to be set based on whether today is before or after 7/1.  If today is before 7/1 then we are in fiscal year that is the current year (so today we are in FY10).  If today is after 7/1 our new fiscal year has started and the variable needs to be the next year (so FY11).

psuedo code:

```
if today < 7/1/anyyear then
  BudgetCode = "1" + thisYear(YY)  //variable will be 110
else
  BudgetCode = "1" + nextYear(YY)  //variable will be 111
```

thanks!

Comment: And 7/1 is July 1st, right? Or is it January 7th?. And the day starts in UTC or in your timezone?

Comment: yes July 1st...in our time zone....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the if statement would be like this to get the 2 digit year with the "1" digit on the front end of it.

```
if (cal.after(someDate)) {
  BudgetCode = "1".concat(new Integer(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)%100).toString());
}
else {
  BudgetCode = "1".concat(new Integer(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)%100).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

if (cal.after(someDate)) {
  fy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
}
else {
  fy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to only get the 2 digit year and not the 4 digit year?  I just need 10 or 11 not 2010 or 2011, thanks

Comment: One way would be the modulus operator, e.g.: int twoDigitFy = fy % 100;